# Opa: How to remove objects from the database?

Tags: opa

I want to delete an object in a db set.

Preferably with a path expression and a conditional.
Something like 
        `delete /wiki/page[content=""]`

If this is not possible, is there *any* other method to delete an object? (Apart from `shift` and `pop`, which only work on db lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Db.remove` on a the reference path (your path starting with @):

```
  Db.remove(@/wiki/page[content=""])
```

Here is an example: https://github.com/tsloughter/OpaDo/blob/master/src/todo.opa#L34